# getting "unrecognized selector" when trying to use Core Data managed object XCode generated class in unit test?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, xcode4, ocunit

Why am I getting "unrecognized selector" when trying to use Core Data managed object XCode generated class in unit test?

That is, in the test case I have to path the method an instanced of a core data managed object (I'm using Xcode 4 generated managed objects).  To aid in keeping the test light weight I through I could just create the object myself (not using the core data framework).  Seemed OK however when I try to use the properties I get "unrecognized selector".

Question are I guess:

1. Why do I get this "unrecognized selector"?
2. How can I modify what I'm doing to create a lightweight version of my core data managed object to be used as input to a method under test in a unit test?

Example of code from managed object.  Eg here using the property "title" would trigger the issue:

```
@interface WEView : NSManagedObject {
  @private
}
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@end


#import "WEView.h"
@implementation WEView
   @dynamic title;
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@dynamic` preprocessor command tells the compiler that the methods will be provided at runtime. It is the managed object context that provides the methods based on information taken from the managed object model. Without the context, the class doesn't have the actual method and can't respond to the selector.

Comment: thanks TechZen - any ideas/thoughts on how can I modify what I'm doing to get a lightweight version of my core data managed object to be used as input to a method under test in a unit test?  (without touching xcode generated managed objects)

Comment: I've never had much success with testing on stubs. You really just end up creating little fake accessors that won't necessarily reproduce the behavior of the real objects.

Comment: I prefer to work with the full fledged Core Data stack within a dedicated testing project i.e. I move the data model and classes to their own project and then just generate data and do testing there. I think this necessary because the object graph is the real heart of Core Data and it is also where the subtle errors show up. If you don't have a realistically large object graph, then you really can't test everything. It's tedious to do this but it does produce the best results. When you are sure the data model works as it should, you have the true guts of your app written.

Comment: ok - what do you do re testing within your app (non coredata component) however? i.e. when you get core data objects from your core data methods (which are in their own project) do you pass these through your app?  In which case testing your app itself would also require you use the real core data classes as well I assume?  (or perhaps once you get a core data object returned you copy it's values to a non-coredata class to use within the app itself?)...

Comment: Yes, I use the real Core Data stack with labeled dummy information all the way through development. Once the data model is nailed down the app is 80% done. Testing isn't particularly useful when dealing with the UI because of the number of UI input permutations. So, I concentrate on testing the data model.